# Book and material to prepare for TOCFL "Test of Chinese as a Foreign Language"

Tags: traditional-characters, books

你好, I have hard time finding books and material to **prepare specifically for TOCFL "Test of Chinese as a Foreign Language"**, NOT HSK.

I am interested in the first level and of course traditional characters.

For example, books with:

> - detailed grammatical points
> - listening comprehension
> - list of vocabulary
> - exercices

*Similar format to what we could find about TOEIC/TOEFL).*

Amazon shows practically nothing bout the subject except some general knowledge material and dictionaries.

> I 've visited the site of ***`sc-toporg.tw`*** I 've found only some
>   online material, but not books:
>   https://www.sc-top.org.tw/english/study.php

Any hints?

谢谢你。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[看圖學中文語法系列（2冊）](http://mtc.ntnu.edu.tw/book/book-show-2.html)

[image]

[華語文能力測驗模擬試題2:入門基礎(Band A)](https://www.shtabook.com/product_2116-%E8%8F%AF%E8%AA%9E%E6%96%87%E8%83%BD%E5%8A%9B%E6%B8%AC%E9%A9%97%E6%A8%A1%E6%93%AC%E8%A9%A6%E9%A1%8C2:%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80%E5%9F%BA%E7%A4%8E(Band%20A).html)

[image]

[華語文能力測驗模擬試題3:入門基礎(Band A)](https://www.shtabook.com/product_4328-%20%E8%8F%AF%E8%AA%9E%E6%96%87%E8%83%BD%E5%8A%9B%E6%B8%AC%E9%A9%97%E6%A8%A1%E6%93%AC%E8%A9%A6%E9%A1%8C3:%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80%E5%9F%BA%E7%A4%8E(Band%20A).html)

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks alot @user-487 for the precious links to the book. You've been of a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s its website for your reference 
Materials: 
https://www.sc-top.org.tw/english/materials.php
Also click “Mock Test” you will get online exercise and free pdf download. It’ll be interesting to learn traditional script. Once you reach a higher level, you will also start to understand simpfiled one without extra effort. Keep learning & Good luck